# How to use clang-tidy with -Wdocumentation flag

Tags: clang-tidy

I want to use my custom check and clang-diagnostics (`-Wdocumentation`) at the same time, but i don't want to have `compile_commands.json` at all.

I tried this:

```
clang-tidy.exe -checks="mycheckmodule-*" -fix-errors %FILE% -- -Wdocumentation
```

but it doesn't work.

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Try this instead: `-extra-arg=-Wdocumentation`, and before `%FILE%`

Comment: Would be helpful to see the error messages.